Error in Llama.Index Text Embeding Inference : get_text_embedding_batch() method
Error received : 1 validation error for EmbeddingEndEvent - embeddings
value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
--
I'm using TEI module from LlamaIndex to get embeddings for an article that is quite long. Knowing that the embedder only accepts maximum 512 character, I'm splitting the article to 512 character using CharacterTextSplitter from langchain.text_splitter module which returns list of string.
The error happen, if the resulting list big enough (more than 50). It works fine if the length of the list is only 3-5.
I read the docs here, it says it expects that the embeddings in EmbeddingEndEvent is a list, but from the documented function, I don't see which part I'm doing wrong. Is there max length of the list that is not documented?

can you share the code?
